# Returning? Returns?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is it okay to say "returnings", as in multiple times going back? For example "Her returnings to the village made everyone suspicious."

I need the word to be plural, any suggestions?

Comment: _revisits_ might fit the bill?

Comment: Does returnings exist in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

**Comings and goings.**

> [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comings-and-goings)
>   "Comings and goings refers to the way people keep arriving at and leaving a particular place. 
>   They noted the comings and goings of the journalists.
>   She had to report her comings and goings to Sister Giuseppe."
>
> [The free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+comings+and+goings)
>   "The arrivals and departures of people at a particular location, and/or their movements and activities. If you want to know about the comings and goings at the pub, talk to Mickey—he's there every day."
>   "Movements, activities, as in He's in and out of the office; I can't keep up with his comings and goings, or In her job on the school board, Mrs. Smith keeps track of all the comings and goings in town ."

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be "returns", as in: "Her returns to the village made everyone suspicious."

However, better options would include using return as an adjective and using another word (e.g. "visits") as the plural noun.  An example would be:

"Her return visits to the village ....".

The plural "returnings" is definitely not appropriate, unless you are intentionally using it for poetic effect.